Using migrations to manage environment variables versioning
Our situation is the following: we are building a SaaS application that has multiple environments (local, test/staging, productions). There is a file on each environment that contains the env-specific configuration variables: URLs and credentials for services our application depends on, various switches, etc.
When we are deploying a new version of our application that starts requiring a new such environment variable, we must keep this in mind, and someone must edit the configuration manually on the affected environments. This feels particularly silly compared to how we've been doing the same thing with the database structure: via database migrations (using Flyway).
My particular questions are:

Is this a thing? How is it called? My googling found nothing useful.
Is there an approach to do this safely for API keys and other secrets that need to be added to the relevant environments?


I understand that you want to automate as much as possible steps when deploying a new environment of your platform.
Short answer is: There is no pre-built tool to do this.
So how do you automate? By making a script yourself.
Basically you want an environment creation script where you create any required credential and store it on the service you like. I would go for something like:
./create-env.sh --name "staging"

And with this command you create any required API key or environment you require, storing them in the service you like.
If you want to store a link to these crendentials on a database (I would not recommend you to store these variables directly on a database) then you basically have to create an application for that. As far as I know there is no service intented for your use case.
Let me know if I can help you further with this.

From your description, it sounds like your deployment approach is to just install a new version of software, so things break whenever the new version of software requires different configuration settings. If that is the case, then perhaps you could change your deployment procedure to be based on a written document that lists one or more steps. One step would be to install the new software, and another (sometimes present) step would specify what changes should be made to configuration files.
What I have suggested above seems obvious to me, which makes me suspect that I am misunderstanding the nature of the problem you are facing. If so, I suggest you edit your question to explain in more detail your current deployment approach.

Hello Ciaran, the steps you describe are essentially what we do now: we explicitly make a note in case a release is supposed to have an update to environment configuration, and we manually update the configuration alongside running our CI/CD pipeline when delivering that change.
However, this is error-prone and obnoxious, so we are looking for an approach similar to how database migrations are typically handled.

It is recommended to use a secure storage like AWS SSM or Parameter Store (or anything similar - easy to find if you wish to search). There can be a separate store for config per environment, or even per deployment. Configuration can be managed separately from deployment this way.
Using something like Terraform or AWS CDK can automate a lot of this for you and remove the need for manual deployment procedures.

Respectfully, I think understanding the definition of CI/CD more deeply is crucial here.  CD = Continuous Delivery, which typically implies an environment is "provisioned", meaning that everything necessary has been set up on the environment, including the software, the configurations - everything.
